# RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (10) must match the existing size (11) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, transformer-model

I am new to implementing transformer model in Pytorch. I have difficulty in implementing the positonal encoder for transformer model. I have input data with shape (128,7,21) where 128 is the batch size, 7 is number of records, and 21 is number of features. The Python code for the positional encoder is written as follow:

```
class PositionalEncoder(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, d_model: int, max_seq_len: int=7):
       super(PositionalEncoder, self).__init__()
       self.d_model = d_model

       # Create positional encoding matrix
       pe = self.positional_encoding(max_seq_len, d_model)
       self.register_buffer('pe', pe)

   def positional_encoding(self, max_seq_len, d_model):
       position = torch.arange(0, max_seq_len).unsqueeze(1).float()
       div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * -(math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
       pe = torch.zeros(max_seq_len, d_model)
       pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
       pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
       return pe

   def forward(self, x):
       # Calculate the sequence length from the input tensor
       seq_len = x.size(1)

       # Add positional encoding to the input along the sequence dimension
       x = x + self.pe[:, :seq_len]
       return x
```

When I execute the above code : `pos_encoder = PositionalEncoder(d_model=21)`, there is **RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (10) must match the existing size (11) at non-singleton dimension 1.  Target sizes: [7, 10].  Tensor sizes: [7, 11]**

The runtime error is generated after `pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)` was executed.

Therefore, how do I solve the runtime error? and I am not sure about what should be the max_seq_len to be set? currently, I am using max_seq_len=7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The slice `pe[:, 1::2]` is of size `(7,10)`. The tensor `torch.cos(position * div_term)` is of size `(7,11)`. As a result, they can't fit together.